# Accessing mdb file in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

We're using access file .mdb file in our wpf project, and this file is created in between ms access 97.

It giving exception like **"Cannot open database ''.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt."**

But it's not always only sometimes it is giving this exception while calling queries using adapters like:

```
tblAccountTableAdapter accountAdapter = new tblAccountTableAdapter();
            DateTime? syskey = accountAdapter.GetSysKeyofAccount(accountNumber);
```

connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data\mmlp.mdb;Persist Security Info=True
```

from above query while calling 'GetSyskeyofAccount()' it's giving above exception and sometimes its giving another query so its not sticking only one query to give exception.

And i tried so many times to find this issue and it's very hard to find where it's giving exceptions in different places.

And my file is only KB in size, so can any one help me out.

Thanks,
nag

Comment: You should show your connection string.

Comment: @ToanVo Please check above question i edited with connection string.

Comment: Sound like your connection string are correct. So I guest you got problem with size of Ms Access file it may be reach to limitation of Ms Access. You should check the size of file if it reach to limitation are 2GB please compact it.

Comment: FYI, you can look at here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310937

Comment: @ToanVo No as i mentioned in the question size is in KB's only

Comment: Is your MDB file allow multiple users access at the same time?

Comment: @ToanVo Thanks for the link, i checked it i've a doubt that we've to do the steps mentioned in the link where ever we deployed our app in the respective machine? since its a window based app.

Comment: @ToanVo No single user only.

Comment: yes. But so far, you should close connection after do any thing. Because keep connection too long at mdb file is a one of root cause lead to MS Access db file get corrupt issue.

Comment: yeah we created queries in adapters itself only, so whenever we call any query it'll create connection and open it then after completion of that query it closes the connection for each query.

Comment: What does the question have to do with WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the machine this is running on and the version of the MDB you are trying to connect to, you might be better using the ACE drivers (or they may, actually be your only choice)

The JET 4.0 drivers will only enable you to read Office formats up to and including Office 2003. For Office 2007 and above, you will need to use the ACE drivers

There are also no 64 bit JET drivers, which might be another reason why you're unable to get connected using JET.

There are, however, both 32 and 64 bit ACE drivers and they are backwards compatible

The driver is available here:
[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

The connection string(s) to use are then detailed here:
[Connection strings for Access 2007](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007#ace-oledb-12-0)

Comment: Hm, while I've experienced the problem you're describing in the past, the error message was never about an unreadable file, but always about the JET driver not being installed...

Comment: It might be that they are running in a 64 bit environment, but do have the 32 bit JET installed though?

Comment: Yes, that's my scenario. I always got an error about the JET driver not being installed when I ran a 64bit/any architecture application on my Windows 7 64 machine until changing it to 32bit only or installing the 64bit driver. I never got an "Invalid file" error.

Comment: It could be that the DB is an Access 2007 DB though, which JET is unable to open (It can only open up to Access 2003 formats)

Comment: See the first line of the question.